# VB6 applications in Windows 10

Tags: vba, vb6, windows-10

I moved a few of my applications to WINDOWS 10 and one of the issue I noticed - which is not really an issue with functionality but rather the colors. Msgboxes seem to not have the top bar anymore (where TITLE goes) - it's actually there, but it's so light that it's difficult to see where the top bar is and the rest of the msg box. does anyone know how to tweak it so that it looks more defined just like it did when it was run in XP or Win7

Comment: it is a default setting..

Comment: Nothing to do with VB 6. All window title bars look like this. They are white and blend in to the window background, which is also white. It's a setting, I can't remember exactly where. Look in the Personalization settings, probably under Color. Or search Google. Make sure you have the latest version of Windows 10; the early versions did not support changing the colors of title bars.

Comment: windows pro 10 version 1511 @CodyGray

Comment: That is the version I happen to have on a Virtual Machine right now. My title bars are a khaki color. Right-click on the desktop, choose "Personalize". The "Settings -> Personalization" dialog will appear. Choose "Colors" in the left-hand side bar, turn off "Automatically pick an accent color", choose one of the accent colors from the palette of options, and then turn on the "Show color on Start, taskbar, action center, and title bar" option below. (The other sites you found and were linked are all for the original version of Windows 10, which didn't support this and required hacks.)

Comment: @CodyGray - Perfect - Thank you lots!

Comment: @CodyGray if you post as answer i'll accept it. The other answer helped me a lot but this resolved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controls implemented from the OS. You need to change properties on the operation system. Maybe this could help:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/change-application-background-color-window-10/167b133e-62f4-4eae-9425-2b9a6019bded

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - in Win 7 you are able to see what the top bar of msg box looks like. Here you are not and changing it to a different accent color doesnt fix the issue.

Comment: I'm running windows 10 pro  version 1511

Comment: it seems to be more complicated than i  to assumed...googled and found this post: http://superuser.com/questions/949920/window-color-and-appearance-removed-in-win10

Comment: you can customize forms (but not Msgboxes)  but i guess that you will not go back to your old Apps and replace all msgboxes with a new personal customized Msgbox.

Comment: yeah we will see what happens - need user input first. Thanks for your help with this.